# Push notification from mobile app to website online users

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to send real time notification from mobile app to web app online users in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 1):

you could use a signalR to set push notification to web user. you can create web api/or web service where the mobile user can call. and the web service/web api can trigger the signalR.

follow the tutorial here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/older-versions/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc-4

and show your code where you stuck and so we can help.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.
But my mobile app and web app both are two applications. How can i trigger signal r from one application to other?
For example: patient is sending notification from mobile app and the doctors can get it in website

Comment: please try the tutorial first then you get a big picture. so it basically a mobile app call the webservice or webapi url with parameter doctorID etc... the signalR will broadcast and push notification. either to another mobile application or the web application.